# Remove object key prefixes nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, javascript-objects

This is my first post. I don't like ask help in forums, but I have no choice. I spent a lot of days trying resolve this but I haven't found any solution.

All my problem start with an database query that returns this.

```
{
"prod_format": "400 ml",
"prod_brand": "Marca",
"prod_image": "192.168.1.45/mini/1046332bb531ab3.jpg",
"prod_name": "Gel de baño o ducha",
"prod_pvp": 2.20,
"prod_shops": [
  {
    "prod_price": 2.29,
    "prod_shop": {
      "prod_shopID": 2,
      "prod_shop_name": "Tienda",
      "prod_shop_image": "192.168.1.45/shops/d4d4sw2.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "prod_price": 2.19,
    "prod_shop": {
      "prod_shopID": 5,
      "prod_shop_name": "Tienda",
      "prod_shop_image": "192.168.1.45/shops/g4hbe72.jpg"
    }
  }
]
}
```

I want remove prefixes of keys, **prod_** and **shop_** in this case.

I can't do this by hand because this is only one of multiple queries that i use, and this data can change, i need an dynamic function that remove these prefixes, to use with more prefixes and more queries.

**So far I have been trying:**

- Recursive function that calls itself to remap inside objects and
  arrays, but it doesn't work because `NodeJS` is asynchronous and make an
  loop that never ends.
- Use an list function that gets all keys/values to make a new object
  with renamed keys, but i cant found anything that works with complex
  objects.
- Use chained promises, i can't get that it works, but i think    that
  it is the best way to do this.

In conclusion I want an function that if I put the upper object, I get this code.

```
{
"format": "400 ml",
"brand": "Marca",
"image": "http://192.168.1.45/mini/1046332bb531ab3.jpg",
"name": "Gel de baño o ducha",
"pvp": 2.20,
"shops": [
  {
    "price": 2.29,
    "shop": {
      "shopID": 2,
      "name": "Tienda",
      "image": "http://192.168.1.45/shops/d4d4sw2.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "price": 2.19,
    "shop": {
      "shopID": 5,
      "name": "Tienda",
      "image": "http://192.168.1.45/shops/g4hbe72.jpg"
    }
  }
]
}
```

PS:
I can't edit the original object, because it comes of `elasticsearch` and i can't edit object keys.

Thanks in advance, I hope that anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply treat your Json data as a string and then replace '`"_prod`' with '`"`'? That would remove all occurances of this prefix.

```
myJsonString.replace('"_prod', '"');
```

Update: If your values may contain your prefixes, you better use regular expressions instead, just to make sure you only change the keys.

Comment: What if there is "_prod" in received data not in a key? It's not likely to happen but it's definitely possible

Comment: Upvoted, but I'll point out that by the looks of his examples what he seems to need is a regex to match the keys and keep only characters after the last underscore.

Comment: Then you should not use it. If this could happen, I would use regular expressions to do the job in a safer way.

Comment: It's not perfectly but i can work, its a It's a temporary patch JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prodInfo._source).replace(new RegExp("prod_","g"),'').replace(new RegExp("shop_","g"),''));